# Bitshift in javascript

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

I've got a really big number: 5799218898. And want to shift it right to 13 bits.
So, windows-calculator or python gives me:

```
5799218898 >> 13 | 100010100100001110011111100001 >> 13
70791            | 10001010010000111
```

As expected.

But Javascript:

```
5799218898 >> 13 | 100010100100001110011111100001 >> 13
183624           | 101100110101001000
```

I think it because of internal integer representation in javascript, but cannot find anything about that.

Comment: The right answer is actually 707912 (10101100110101001000) which makes it clearer that the first two binary digits are getting chopped off.

Comment: [BigInts](https://v8.dev/features/bigint) will help you `console.log((1n << 32n).toString())`, but the support is not quite there ..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In ECMAScript (Javascript) bitwise operations are always in 32-bit. Therefore 5799218898 is chopped into 32-bit which becomes 1504251602. This integer >> 13 gives 183624.

In Python they are arbitrary-length integers. So there's no problem.

(And the numbers in Windows calculator are 64-bit, enough to fit 5799218898.)

(And the correct answer should be 707912.)

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Looks like I can emulate this behavior in python like this (5799218898 & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> 13

Answer (score 6):

If you have a modern browser, you might want to use bigint for values greater than 32-bit signed. They were introduced in the 11-th Edition of ECMAScript Language back in 2020.

It is stated, you also find a browser compatibility table:

> Bitwise operators are supported as well, except >>> (zero-fill right shift), as every BigInt value is signed.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

You can do the following, tested for example in Chrome:

```
> Number(BigInt(5799218898) >> BigInt(13))
<- 707912
```

Answer (score 4):

As Nicholas Zakas [states](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/08/computer-science-in-javascript-base64-encoding/):

> Even though JavaScript numbers are
>   technically stored in 64-bits, integer
>   values are treated as if they’re 32
>   bits whenever bitwise operators are
>   involved.

Answer (score 2):

The number you have (5799218898) is beyond 32 bits. You didn't mention the JavaScript engine you're testing with, but it's very likely that it is 32-bit.

To test, trim the "5" at the beginning of your number so that you fall inside the 32-bit boundary. Then your shift should work fine.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.6 on 64bit system

Comment: All JavaScript engines use 64-bit floating point numbers, and convert to 32-bit integers for bitwise operations, regardless of the architecture. It's defined in the ECMAScript standard.