# Truncate a double variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate Decimal number not Round Off in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912788/truncate-decimal-number-not-round-off-in-jquery)

I have values like `5.3777777`, `4.6666666` on my `Y` variable.

How can I truncate it so it shows 5.3 or 5.6 instead with JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please try a few searches such as "javascript truncate number" (-1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to do this in any language is to multiple the value by the inverse of the precision required, truncate, and then divide again:

```
var truncated = Math.floor(val * 10) / 10;
```

If you want strict *rounding* rather than *truncation* then Javascript also has [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) built-in which does this for you.

Comment: `toFixed()` rounds the number, it doesn't truncate it.

Comment: @Juhana text updated, thanks...

Comment: What if `val` is negative? (OK, probably negatives make a good "exercise for the reader"...)

Comment: As nnnnnn says, this might produce unexpected results when the numbers are negative (it depends on what your expectations are). To handle the negative case check the question this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912788/truncate-not-round-off-decimal-numbers-in-javascript