# Is there a data type for decimals that doesn't round?

Tags: javascript, css, floating-point, width

I know floating point numbers round, so is there a data type I can use like a floating point number  that doesn't round?  My specific problem is 9.9999999999999999 is returning 10 when I need it to return 9.9999999999999999.

Also, can I set an elemen't width to that value (CSS, like `.style.width=9.9999999999999999`)?

Comment: There's no native decimal number in JavaScript, use a library or a specific format (string, array of digits, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [Truncate (not round off) decimal numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912788/truncate-not-round-off-decimal-numbers-in-javascript)

It seems to be a very similar use case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better question is: why do you need `9.9999999999999999`? If you just want the floating point number that is just smaller than 10, then that is `9.999999999999998` (okay, technically it is `9.9999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875`, but `9.999999999999998` should round to this value).

Comment: Hello, sorry to gravedig four years later but this was a very hypothetical question