# How to truncate (not round) a particular number after decimal point using javascript

Tags: javascript

> input : -81.82637799999999(14 numbers after decimal point)
>
> output :-81.8263779999999(13 numbers after decimal point)

How can I implement this using javascript?

Comment: convert to string split the string 13 places after decimal point, then parse to int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate (not round off) decimal numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912788/truncate-not-round-off-decimal-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: @thisOneGuy parsint to int is not going to keep the truncated decimal part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try this.
See if it works for you

```
var x = -81.82637799999999;
x = x.toString(); // convert to string
alert(x.length);
x = x.substring(0, x.length - 1); // cut out last character
alert(x.length);
x = parseFloat(x); // convert it back to float
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9sngtp3n/1/