# Round down decimals javascript

Tags: javascript, input, numbers, decimal, rounding

I am working on a JS project and i have the following  problem:

My input number goes from 0 to 10. (it can  be 1, 2, **3.4**, **5,9**, etc..)

The expected output would be something out of 5 with **only one lowered down** decimal.

**Examples:**

9.7 / 10  would  give 4.85 / 5 , the output  has to be **4.8** (keep only one lowered down digit)

4.9  / 10 would give 2.45 / 5, the output  has to be **2.4** (keep only one lowered down digit)

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: This has been answered before at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912788/truncate-not-round-off-decimal-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a simple process:

1. Multiply your number by 10.
2. *Floor* it ([using `Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)).
3. Divide it by 10.

```js
Math.floor(4.85 * 10) / 10; // 4.8
Math.floor(2.45 * 10) / 10; // 2.4
Math.floor(3 * 10) / 10;    // 3
```

Taking 4.85 as an example:

1. `4.85 * 10` equates to `48.5`.
2. `Math.floor(48.5)` equates to `48`.
3. `48 / 10` equates to `4.8`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var x = 9.7; // input variable
var base = 10; //base like 10 in your case

var outof = 5; //rounded out of

Number(String((x/base)*outof).match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?/)) //outputs one rounded off value for last digit;
```

last line will first compute the value which is

```
var value = (x/base)*outof;
```

then get only first digit after decimal

```
value = value.match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?/);
```

convert the final value to a number

```
value = Number ( value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this ugly to you?

Convert to string --> substring --> convert to number

```
var x = 9.47;
var x2 = (x+'').split(".");
x = parseFloat(x2[0]+"."+x2[1].substr(0,1));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.toFixed()`

For example

```
var N=2.45;

alert(N.toFixed(1));
```

will return `2.4`

Comment: Won't ToFixed cause rounding?

Comment: toFixed will cause rounding

Comment: Yes, it will do rounding

Comment: it returns `2.5` can u try it?

Comment: He asked for an answer that did not round up so I don't think toFixed will be useful here.

Answer (score -1):

```
var x = 4.8555;
x = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100;
alert(x.toFixed(1));
```

Comment: This does not work, it rounds to the higher decimal.

Comment: this will alert only 4.8 and you can run this one also sir

Comment: No, because 4.86 will return 4.9, the objective is to return 4.8

Comment: Well, it does not work .. open your console and  type 

var x = 4.98;
x = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100;
alert(x.toFixed(1));

it will return 5.0 instead of 4.9