# remove a few numbers after decimal point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

this should be an easy one, but im stuck with the code i currently have!

[image]

```js
   render: (value) => {
     return <span><b>{value}</b>%</span>;
   },
```

im trying to render the value, bold with the percentage sign as a suffix while rounding it down to only two digits after the decimal point :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate (not round off) decimal numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912788/truncate-not-round-off-decimal-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Number.prototype.toFixed()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
return <span><b>{value.toFixed(2)}</b>%</span>;
```

**Please Note:** If value is string type then you have to convert that to number first:

```
return <span><b>{Number(value).toFixed(2)}</b>%</span>;
```