# How to convert human readable memory size into bytes?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to convert strings that match `/(\d)+(\.\d+)?(m|g|t)?b?/i` into bytes.

For example, **1KB** would return **1024**. **1.2mb** would return **1258291**.

Comment: i don't care about calculating bits in this situation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you reorganize the capturing group in your regex  like so: `/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s?(k|m|g|t)?b?/i`
you can do something like:

```
function unhumanize(text) { 
    var powers = {'k': 1, 'm': 2, 'g': 3, 't': 4};
    var regex = /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s?(k|m|g|t)?b?/i;

    var res = regex.exec(text);

    return res[1] * Math.pow(1024, powers[res[2].toLowerCase()]);
}

unhumanize('1 Kb')
# 1024
unhumanize('1 Mb')
# 1048576
unhumanize('1 Gb')
# 1073741824
unhumanize('1 Tb')
# 1099511627776
```

Comment: If you stored powers of 2 in the table instead of powers of 1024, you could use a bitshift for the calculation (which is generally much faster that the power function).

Comment: @vol7ron: You should take that complaint up with the question which uses them interchangeably, not the answer.

Comment: @ben: I take it up with both, and will change the vote when it has changed, otherwise not a bad solution

Comment: @Ben : sadly the bit shifting in javascript is mostly 32 bit (depending on the js engine of course) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373791/bitshift-in-javascript so : `1 << 32 === 1`.

Comment: @vol7ron: Thanks for the feed back i didn't see that -:) well hope the OP have seen that and will correct my leak .

Comment: @mouad: That's unfortunate :(  And so 1992.

Comment: Works great but I'm not sure it handles numbers that are less than 1k (my use case is creating a D3 graph from `du -h` output).

Answer (score 3):

You've already got a capturing group for the unit prefix, now all you need is a lookup table:

```
{ 'k', 1L<<10 },
{ 'M', 1L<<20 },
{ 'G', 1L<<30 },
{ 'T', 1L<<40 },
{ 'P', 1L<<50 },
{ 'E', 1L<<60 }
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/5O7Vp

Although `1258291` is clearly far too many significant digits to get from `1.2MB`.

oops, I gave a C# example.  The method is still good though.

Comment: @DeaDEnD: I'm not shifting floats.  You can multiply a float by the integer result of a shift just fine.

Comment: ah ok I didn't understand it fully at first

Comment: Hmmm... `1 << 10 === 1024` `1 << 20 === 1048576` `1 << 30 === 1073741824` **`1 << 40 === 256`** **`1 << 50 === 262144`** **`1 << 60 === 268435456`**.

Comment: @yckart: You forgot the `L`.

Comment: @BenVoigt `L` does not exist in javascript. Is there an equivalent for this?

Answer (score 1):

One liner solution:

```
"1.5 MB".replace(/(\d+)+(\.(\d+))?\s?(k|m|g|t)?b?/i, function(value, p1, p2, p3, p4) { return parseFloat(p1 + (p2 || ""))*({ 'K' : 1<<10, 'M' : 1<<20, 'G' : 1<<30, 'T' : 1<<40 }[p4] || 1); })

# 1572864
```