# Size of objects in memory during an IPython session (with Guppy?)

Tags: python, memory-management, ipython, heapy, guppy

I recall [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563840/how-can-i-check-the-memory-usage-of-objects-in-ipython?rq=1) that it is hard to pin down the exact memory usage of objects in Python. However, that thread is from 2009, and since then I have read about various memory profilers in Python (see the examples in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331471/in-memory-size-of-python-stucture)). Also, IPython has matured substantially in recent months (version 1.0 was released a few days ago)

IPython already has a magic called  `whos`, that prints the variable names, their types and some basic Data/Info.

In a similar fashion, is there any way to get the size in memory of each of the objects returned by `who`
? Any utilities available for this purpose already in IPython?

## Using Guppy

[Guppy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/)  (suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended)) has a command that allows one to get the **cummulative** memory usage **per object type**, but unfortunately:

1. It does not show memory usage **per object**
2. It prints the sizes in bytes (not in human readable format)

For the second one, it may be possible to apply `bytes2human` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13449587/283296), but I would need to first collect the output of `h.heap()` in a format that I can parse.

But for the first one (the most important one), is there any way to have Guppy show memory usage **per object**?

```
In [6]: import guppy

In [7]: h = guppy.hpy()                                                                                                                                     

In [8]: h.heap()
Out[8]: 
Partition of a set of 2871824 objects. Total size = 359064216 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 522453  18 151469304  42 151469304  42 dict (no owner)
     1 451503  16 36120240  10 187589544  52 numpy.ndarray
     2 425700  15 34056000   9 221645544  62 sklearn.grid_search._CVScoreTuple
     3 193439   7 26904688   7 248550232  69 unicode
     4 191061   7 22696072   6 271246304  76 str
     5 751128  26 18027072   5 289273376  81 numpy.float64
     6  31160   1 12235584   3 301508960  84 list
     7 106035   4  9441640   3 310950600  87 tuple
     8   3300   0  7260000   2 318210600  89 dict of 0xb8670d0
     9   1255   0  3788968   1 321999568  90 dict of module
<1716 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

Comment: ... wait: you want to know the size of each one of the `522453` `dict` instances, `451503` `numpy.ndarray` instances etc? AFAIK there isn't any library/profiler doing this. I'd also point out that, for example, information on `numpy.ndarray` will be wrong since `numpy` does not use `PyMem_MALLOC`, but uses `malloc` directly(hence every non-numpy aware profile wont be able to correctly inspect the size of the arrays).

Comment: @Bakuriu, not quite, I would like to know the size of each of the objects in the current frame without recursion (i.e. those listed by `who` in IPython). Just updated the OP to clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use something like:

```
h.heap().byid
```

But this will only show you immediate sizes (i.e. not the total size of a list including the other lists it might refer to).

If you have a particular object you wish to get the size of you can use:

```
h.iso(object).domisize
```

To find the approximate amount of memory that would freed if it were deleted.