# Difference in the results of operations bitwise between javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, bitwise-operators

Javascript code:

```
console.log( 1 << 5 );
console.log( 1111044149 << 2 );
```

Javascript output:

```
32
149209300
```

PHP code:

```
var_dump( 1 << 5 );
var_dump( 1111044149 << 2 );
```

PHP output:

```
32
4444176596
```

Why `1111044149 << 2` has difference between PHP and javascript? I'm writing a javascript code to PHP and everything worked less that part and I need the PHP code shows similar results obtained in javascript to be perfect.

Comment: might be to large an integer for JS...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitshift in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373791/bitshift-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

The operands of a bitwise operation in JavaScript are always treated as int32, and in PHP this is not the case. So, when performing the left shift on `1111044149`, this happens in JS:

```
01000010001110010011000000110101 (original, 32-bit)

00001000111001001100000011010100 (left shifted 2 positions, "01" is truncated)
= 149209300
```

And in PHP, the bits do not get truncated because it is not treated as a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Actually, JS numbers are 64b floats. If the php output had been wrong, it would have been easy to explain due to overflow.

Comment: @Jite Indeed they are, but bitwise operations in JS work with 32-bit integers.

Comment: @ProgramFOX I had no idea of this. Thank you for info! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanations, helped me a lot and I could now make a function to handle this automatically conversion, I had forgotten that detail about 32-bit and 64-bit for lack of attention.

Function

```
function shift_left_32( $a, $b ) {
    return ( $c = $a << $b ) && $c >= 4294967296 ? $c - 4294967296 : $c;
}
```

Test

```
var_dump( shift_left_32( 1, 5 ) );
var_dump( shift_left_32( 1111044149, 2 ) );
```

Output

```
32
149209300
```