# Bitwise operations PHP and JS different

Tags: javascript, php, bit-manipulation

Why does php and js give different results to the same thing:
JS:

```
1085 << 24 = 1023410176
```

PHP:

```
1085 << 24 = 18203279360
```

Comment: js bit operations are as if on 32bit int. I dont know about php, 1085 << 24 goes beyond 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

The operands of a bitwise operation in JavaScript are always treated as int32, and in PHP this is not the case.

And in PHP, the bits do not get truncated because it is not treated as a 32-bit integer.

[Difference in the results of operations bitwise between javascript and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726466/difference-in-the-results-of-operations-bitwise-between-javascript-and-php)