# PHP equivalent of bitwise operation NodeJs script

Tags: php, node.js

I'm trying to convert a pretty simple function from NodeJs to PHP.
I think I found out how to convert 80% of it, but I am stuck around bitwise operators.

This is the original NodeJs script:

```
function convert(encodedString) {
  let bytes = new Buffer.from(encodedString, 'base64')
  let code = bytes[bytes.length - 1]
  code ^= 91

  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length - 1; ++i) {
    bytes[i] = ((bytes[i] ^ (code << (i % 5))) | 0)
  }

  return bytes
}
```

And this is the converted PHP version

```
function convert($encoded)
{
    $bytes = unpack('C*', base64_decode($encoded));
    $code = $bytes[count($bytes)];
    $code ^= 91;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($bytes) - 1; ++$i) {
        $bytes[$i + 1] = (($bytes[$i + 1] ^ ($code << ($i % 5))) | 0);
    }  

    return $bytes;
}
```

This somehow works until the bitwise part. I get the correct result for the first element of the array, but all the consequent values are wrong. I also had to adapt indexing because with the unpack method i get an base-1 index array.

If I loop each array's value before the conversion, I have the same result on both scripts, so I think is correct until that.

I was able to reproduce the issue on NodeJs, if for example I define a normal array (with same values) instead using Buffer.

I don't really know how to reproduce the same behaviour in PHP.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think the ` | 0` part doesn't translate directly into PHP (I think).

Comment: Thanks Nigel. The point is that if I for example edit the NodeJS code using b[i] = instead of using bytes[i] = (so using a normal array), I have the same exact behaviour as on PHP. I don't know if the difference is the Buffer array or what else.

Comment: Is `$bytes` 1-based array instead of 0-based? Force it to be 0-based with `$bytes = array_merge(unpack('C*', base64_decode($encoded)));` then you can deal with indexes without changing `$i` and focus on bitwise operators.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the tip Triby!

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise operators in Javascript and PHP handle calucations differently.

Example:

Javascript:

```
1085 << 24 = 1023410176
```

PHP:

```
1085 << 24 = 18203279360
```

[Bitwise operations PHP and JS different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518081/bitwise-operations-php-and-js-different)

You should write your own function for bitwise operators in PHP.
[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: Thanks Tajniak. If that's the reason, I can't understand why if I use a normal array in JS I have the exact same result.