# Bit shift difference JavaScript and Python

Tags: javascript, python, byte, bit-shift

I am working on a mobile app, it needs to do bit shifting at some point of the code.

I ran into a bug which is certainly puzzling, and if I do it on Python it runs well.

JavaScript:

```js
1000>>32 // resulting in 1000
```

[image: shiftJS]

Python:

```py
1000>>32 // resulting in 0
```

[image: shiftPy]

Why the same operation brings back different result?

Comment: `Number(BigInt(1000) >> BigInt(32))`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373791/bitshift-in-javascript

Comment: In JS all bitwise operators are signed 32bit, so >> 32 is the same as no shift